# Edit notifications do not push the site's background image down

Tags: bug, edits, design, notifications

If someone edits a post you are currently editing, you will receive this notification:

[image]

Notice that it pushes the site's logo and navigation links down. It leaves the background image in place, though.

Comment: I think that looks neat.  [meta-tag:feature]